# Unable to delete a row from database in android (sql query is empty after the where clause)

Tags: android, sqlite

For some reason the sql query is not complete,

> DELETE FROM activations WHERE smsArrivalTimeStamp =

**The Exception**

```
01-08 16:19:01.447: E/AndroidRuntime(4659): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM activations WHERE smsArrivalTimeStamp =
01-08 16:19:01.447: E/AndroidRuntime(4659):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
```

**The Code**

```
public void deleteActivation(long timeStamp) {
        String selection = God.COLUMN_NAME_SMS_ARRIVAL_TIME_STAMP + " = ";
        String[] selectionArgs = { String.valueOf(timeStamp) };
        System.out.println("Selections Args "+ selectionArgs[0]) ;
        God.activationsDB.getWritableDatabase().delete(God.TABLE_ACTIVATIONS,
                selection, selectionArgs);
    }
```

The system.out is printing

```
01-08 16:06:50.887: I/System.out(4295): Selections Args 1420704490320
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**?(Question mark symbol)** is required for `selection` statement

Change this

```
 String selection = God.COLUMN_NAME_SMS_ARRIVAL_TIME_STAMP + " = ";
```

into

```
 String selection = God.COLUMN_NAME_SMS_ARRIVAL_TIME_STAMP + " = ?";
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought that the ? was for a LIKE, crazy me.. Thanks a ton